# Running npm run dev in dockerfile

Tags: npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to dockerise a laravel app. I'm using laravel mix based on webpack. Without docker, npm run dev works. But inside docker, I get this error message, that is not explicit, I don't understand what is wrong, and what should I change

```
95% emitting ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors22:20:53                          

 error  in ./resources/assets/images/login_cover.jpg

Module build failed: Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:841:14)

 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":false,"ident":"postcss","plugins":[null]}!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less 7:150621-150660 7:403139-403178
 @ ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/vue/pages/userForm.js ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less

 error  in ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:841:14)
    at runLoaders (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /app/node_modules/img-loader/index.js:45:31
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)

                                                                    Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                                                /css/pages/userCreate.css    12.8 kB          [emitted]         
  fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1    20.1 kB          [emitted]         
 fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff?fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158    23.4 kB          [emitted]         
  fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512    45.4 kB          [emitted]         
 images/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg?f0ea477ef046ba5fef9249ec3172903e    93.9 kB          [emitted]         
                     images/seamless.png?8b9eb18dd056013d16b945613a1ca86f    2.14 kB          [emitted]         
                     images/boxed_bg.png?612698606760cf487e1741a80d829c67    9.02 kB          [emitted]         
              images/boxed_bg_retina.png?9cb3712430796f112d1dca8baffb7200    27.6 kB          [emitted]         
                                                             /js/oauth.js     953 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/oauth
                                                         /js/bootstrap.js     886 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  /js/bootstrap
                                                  /js/addFighterToTeam.js    69.7 kB       2  [emitted]         /js/addFighterToTeam
                                                    /js/kendo-settings.js    35.9 kB       3  [emitted]         /js/kendo-settings
                                                    /js/createCategory.js    30.4 kB       4  [emitted]         /js/createCategory
                                                          /js/userForm.js    7.63 kB       5  [emitted]         /js/userForm
                                                         /js/analytics.js  474 bytes          [emitted]         
                             /vendor/laravel-tournaments/css/brackets.css    2.67 kB          [emitted]         
                                                     /css/pages/sheet.css  934 bytes          [emitted]         
                                    /css/icons/icomoon/fonts/icomoon.woff     218 kB          [emitted]         
                                     /css/icons/icomoon/fonts/icomoon.ttf     218 kB          [emitted]         
                                                               /js/app.js     365 kB          [emitted]         
                                                         /js/guest_app.js     153 kB          [emitted]         
                              /resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less    13.3 kB          [emitted]         
                                                             /css/app.css     633 kB          [emitted]         
                                     /js/pages/header/tournamentCreate.js     146 kB          [emitted]         
                                           /js/pages/header/userCreate.js    63.9 kB          [emitted]         
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb      18 kB          [emitted]         
                                                          /js/userEdit.js    64.4 kB          [emitted]         
                                            /css/pages/tournamentEdit.css    1.58 kB          [emitted]         
                                       /js/pages/header/tournamentEdit.js     297 kB          [emitted]         
                                                 /js/pages/footer/club.js    8.23 kB          [emitted]         
                                       /js/pages/header/tournamentShow.js    97.5 kB          [emitted]         
                                      /js/pages/header/tournamentIndex.js    13.9 kB          [emitted]         
                                     /js/pages/header/competitorCreate.js    73.5 kB          [emitted]         
                                      /js/pages/header/competitorIndex.js     160 kB          [emitted]         
                                     /js/pages/header/tournamentInvite.js     107 kB          [emitted]         
                                          /css/pages/tournamentInvite.css  840 bytes          [emitted]         
                                                /js/pages/footer/trees.js      78 kB          [emitted]         
                                                     /css/pages/trees.css    2.67 kB          [emitted]         
                                         /css/pages/preliminary_trees.css  293 bytes          [emitted]         
                                 /js/pages/footer/tournamentEditFooter.js    11.3 kB          [emitted]         
                              /js/pages/footer/tournamentDeletedFooter.js    1.24 kB          [emitted]         
                                /js/pages/footer/tournamentIndexFooter.js    6.07 kB          [emitted]         
                                 /js/pages/footer/tournamentShowFooter.js  648 bytes          [emitted]         
                                      /js/pages/footer/userIndexFooter.js    4.87 kB          [emitted]         
                                       /js/pages/footer/userShowFooter.js  752 bytes          [emitted]         
                               /js/pages/footer/associationIndexFooter.js    2.99 kB          [emitted]         
                                      /js/pages/footer/clubIndexFooter.js    3.73 kB          [emitted]         
                                      /js/pages/footer/teamIndexFooter.js    3.28 kB          [emitted]         
                                                         /css/dragula.css    2.05 kB          [emitted]         
                                                          /js/facebook.js  851 bytes          [emitted]         

ERROR in ./resources/assets/images/login_cover.jpg
Module build failed: Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:841:14)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"sourceMap":false,"ident":"postcss","plugins":[null]}!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less 7:150621-150660 7:403139-403178
 @ ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/vue/pages/userForm.js ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less

ERROR in ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:841:14)
    at runLoaders (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at /app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (/app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /app/node_modules/img-loader/index.js:45:31
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
 @ ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/vue/pages/userForm.js ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-15T22_20_53_900Z-debug.log
```

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in image-webpack-loader https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader/issues/142

Comment: yep, I saw that, but I don't really know how to deal with it, as I use laravel mix...

Comment: Larabel mix is just a configuration level on top of webpack. The easiest solution might be to use a custom webpack config and downgrade that to 3.x which doesn't have the bug until it is fixed. Not ideal, but I don't have a different idea, sorry.

Comment: weird thing is when I execute the same command without container, it works without any problem

Comment: it seems like it is a Ubuntu thing only, I can't reproduce it in Arch. Is this what you are using as the docker image? I've looked into image-webpack-loader and imagemin, but they don't do a lot of magic. My guess is the problem is in between node and mozjpeg. But I have no idea how this is related to the webpack version. You could try a different distro, or converting the image to png?

Comment: I tried with ubuntu and centos and it fails. Both were with docker. when I execute the same thing without docker on mac, it passes